# group_by() and summarize() is not resulting in one row in the output for each group

Tags: data-preprocessing

I am learning basics of {dplyr} package in R and working with `summarize()` function. When I create groups using `group_by()` function, output does not result in summary rows for each group.

**The data frame is:**

```
head(titanic_df)

  Class    Sex   Age Survived Freq
1   1st   Male Child       No    0
2   2nd   Male Child       No    0
3   3rd   Male Child       No   35
4  Crew   Male Child       No    0
5   1st Female Child       No    0
```

Now I group the df by `Class`:

```
head(titanic_df %>% group_by(Class))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Class [4]
  Class Sex    Age   Survived  Freq
  <fct> <fct>  <fct> <fct>    <dbl>
1 1st   Male   Child No           0
2 2nd   Male   Child No           0
3 3rd   Male   Child No          35
4 Crew  Male   Child No           0
5 1st   Female Child No           0
```

This is fine. But when I try to summarize the variable `Freq` in this grouped df, output is not grouped by `Class`.

```
titanic_df %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  summarize(num_passg_class = sum(Freq))

  num_passg_class
1            2201
```

The output is a single row of sum of the entire `Freq` column, not segregated by Class. Am I missing something?

I am expecting following results:

```
tapply(titanic_df$Freq, titanic_df$Class, sum)

 1st  2nd  3rd Crew 
 325  285  706  885
```

PS: This is my first attempt to write formatted R codes at this forum, hope I haven't been terrible at it.

Comment: Which package is the `titanic_df` from?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
  titanic_df %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  summarise(num_passg_class = sum(Freq))
```

which will produce something like this (I made up the numbers as I couldn't find the dataset, but it is based on what you provided):

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Class num_passg_class
  <chr>           <dbl>
1 1st                 4
2 2nd                 4
3 3rd                 6
4 Child              10
5 Crew                8
```

Or this which is `spread`:

```
titanic_df %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  summarise(num_passg_class = sum(Freq)) %>% 
  spread(Class, num_passg_class)
```

Which is this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  `1st` `2nd` `3rd` Child  Crew
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     4     6    10     8
```

Comment: `titanic_df` is an object I created from the `Titanic` dataset available with `{dplyr}` package to convert the original _table_ into a _dataframe_. `summarize()` and `summarise()` both work (the help says both are synonymous), only `summarise` was valid with earlier versions of the package. I figured, I had both {dplyr} and {plyr} package attached, which was creating this issue (don't have a clue why, any comments?). Now when I detached {plyr}, its working fine.

Comment: Still, I am getting error if I use the `spread()` function you suggested: ```Error in spread(., Class, num_passg_class) : could not find function "spread" ```

Comment: `spread` is in `tidyr`. Load either `tidyr` or the `tidyverse`.